Randomly Generating Real-Rooted Polynomial Equations
I need a simple function to generate real-rooted polynomial functions to demo my Desmos Aberth-Ehrlich rootfinding implementation.
My current function is as follows:
Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be the polynomial degree.
Let $r_0, r_1, \dots, r_{n-1}, r_n$ be the randomly generated roots of the polynomial, where $-n \le r_i \le n$.
Then, $p(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-r_i)$.
My method of generating random roots is, in Desmos:

$2n\text{random}(n)-n$

Where the $\text{random}(n)$ function generates a set of $n$ random numbers $\in [0,1]$.
This works, but when plotted, there are a few problems:

Roots often appear very close together which makes them difficult to see.
When $n \ge 5$, turning points have high $y$-values, meaning they are off screen.

Simply, I want most of the generated polynomials to look good and be well framed on screen, but they aren't at the moment.
Desmos implementation of Aberth-Ehrlich method.

Your first question about the roots being too close together can be solved by multiplying the root by some constant $c$ greater than one, as shown below:
$$p(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-cr_i).$$
Your second question is where it gets difficult. I only found solutions for polynomials of degree two and three. Unfortunately, finding solutions for anything higher would be quite cumbersome. But, if you wish, I believe the same method can be used for those cases.
However, if you do not care too much, just divide the polynomial by $100$ or some other number to help flatten it out.
n=2
Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cjnepk67li
The problem in your implementation on Desmos is that the polynomial is being multiplied by $X[n+1]$. We need to find a better number that consistently bounds the polynomial to the viewing area. Call this number $a$. We have that
$$p(z)=a\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-cr_i)=a(z-cr_1)(z-cr_2).$$
To keep it consistent with my Desmos graph, have $s=cr_1$ and $q=cr_2$. The objective is to bound the extremum values to be within $[-10,10]$. The derivative of $p(z)$ is $a(2z-q-s)$. Setting the derivative equal to zero to find the critical points, we find that $z=\frac{q+s}{2}$.
As the maximum value of the function is $10$, the critical point when plugged into the function should give us $10$. We then solve for $a$.
$$10=a\left(\frac{q+s}{2}-s\right)\left(\frac{q+s}{2}-q\right)$$
$$a=\frac{40}{(q-s)(s-q)}.$$
So far, we have that $p(z)=\frac{40}{(q-s)(s-q)}(z-cr_1)(z-cr_2)$. However, we are not done. The function always obtains a maximum of $10$. We want the extremum value to be some value in the interval $[-10,10]$, not necessarily $10$. To do this, we need to multiply $a$ by a random number and make sure this number keeps the important bits of the function in the viewing rectangle. The source below from Reddit gives a formula to give that random number:
https://www.reddit.com/r/desmos/comments/1bm9ijr/whats_an_easy_way_i_can_generate_a_number_between/.
The solution for $n=2$ is
$$p(z)=(-2a \cdot \mathbb{random()}+a)(z-s)(z-q),$$
where $\mathbb{random()}$ generates a random number between $0$ and $1$.
n=3
Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kfj0gcyo7v
Bad implementation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/71s1wzzuqn
My graph does not exactly match yours because of the random nature of the functions. I do not know enough about Desmos to solve that problem. Still, I believe it is close enough to what you want. Anyways, this is where it gets ugly.
Our polynomial is now $p(z)=a(z-cr_1)(z-cr_2)(z-cr_3)=a(z-s)(z-q)(z-t)$. Like before, we will find the critical points $b_1$ and $b_2$, set the polynomial equal to $10$, and solve for $a$. So
$$p'(z)=3z^2+2(-q-s-r)z+(qr+sr+sq)=0,$$
$$b_1=\frac{q+s+t+\sqrt{q^2+s^2+t^2-sq-qt-st}}{3},$$
$$b_2=\frac{q+s+t-\sqrt{q^2+s^2+t^2-sq-qt-st}}{3}.$$
We have two solutions, two values of what $a$ can be. Call those values $a_1$ and $a_2$. Like when $n=2$, we have that
$$10=p(b_1)=a_1(b_1-s)(b_1-q)(b_1-t),$$
$$10=p(b_2)=a_2(b_2-s)(b_2-q)(b_2-t).$$
After solving,
$$a_1=\frac{10}{(b_1-s)(b_1-q)(b_1-t)}$$
$$a_2=\frac{10}{(b_2-s)(b_2-q)(b_2-t)}.$$
Unlike the $n=2$ case, we are not done. Cubic polynomials may have both a relative maximum and a relative minimum. The minimum may be less than $-10$ even though the maximum is at most $10$. To counter this issue, two new similar functions will be used. We have differing values of $a$, so two new possible functions that $p(z)$ can be:
$$f(z)=a_1(z-s)(z-q)(z-t),$$
$$g(z)=a_2(z-s)(z-q)(z-t).$$
Observe the nice properties each function has. The maximum value of $f(z)$ is $f(b_1)=10$ while the minimum is unknown. The maximum value of $g(z)$ is $g(b_2)=10$ while the minimum is unknown. Even more interesting is that $g(b_1)=\frac{100}{f(b_2)}$. From tinkering around on Desmos, I stumbled across the following useful theorem.
Let $f(b_1)=10$ and $g(b_2)=10$ both be relative maximum values for their respective function. If $f(b_2)<-10$, then $g(b_1)>-10$.
Proof: Assume that $f(b_2)<-10$. Then $f(b_2)=\frac{10}{(b_1-s)(b_1-q)(b_1-t)}(b_2-s)(b_2-q)(b_2-t)<-10$. Since $g(b_1)=\frac{100}{f(b_2)}$, it follows that $100=f(b_2)g(b_1)$. As $f(b_2)$ is negative, and $100$ is positive, $g(b_1)$ is negative. As multiplying by a negative number switches the inequality sign, $100=f(b_2)g(b_1)>-10g(b_1)$. After dividing by $-10$, we have that $-10<g(b_1)$. $\blacksquare$
Basically, the theorem tells us to use $g(z)$ as our polynomial when the other function, $f(z)$, has a minimum not in the viewing rectangle, a minimum less than $-10$. We know that $g(b_1)$ is a minimum ($b_1$ is a critical point), and now we know from the theorem that $g(b_1)$ is in the viewing rectangle. Below is our hard work before it is applied to Desmos:
$$f(z)=a_1(z-s)(z-q)(z-t)$$
$$p(z)=\begin{cases}
a_1(z-s)(z-q)(z-t) & f(b_2) \geq -10 \\
a_2(z-s)(z-q)(z-t) & f(b_2) < -10
\end{cases}$$
I know the first case uses $f(z)$ itself, but I needed $f(z)$ for the conditions.
n>3
There is probably another method I do not know about that should be used. As I said in the beginning, you could divide your polynomial by 100 to flatten it out.
